# Will setTimeout run when browser is not in focus? (OS X App Nap)

Tags: javascript, macos, settimeout

I'm just wondering if setTimeout based timer will run properly on OS X when the browser running it is out of focus (e.g.: browser is in fullscreen mode and user is on another desktop/application). Does the App Nap feature interfere with running JavaScripts as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does interfere with any running JS because App Nap prevents "unnecessary" things running in the background in order to save power.

In addition, there isn't any way to disable App Nap for performance reasons.

See [this SE post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/132920/disable-app-nap-via-javascript-html) for a little more information.